# Azure Durable Functions, unexpected value of 'IsReplaying' flag

Tags: azure, function

I'm trying to understand Azure Durable Functions behavior.  Specifically about how the Orchestrator function gets replayed.  I thought I was getting the hang of it until I found one value of the Context.IsReplaying flag that didn't make sense to me.

My code is very "hello world" -ish.  It has an Orchestrator function that calls two Activity functions one after the other.

```
[FunctionName("OrchestratorFn")]
    public static async Task<object> Orchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        ILogger log
        ) {
        log.LogInformation($"--------> Orchestrator started at {T()}, isReplay={context.IsReplaying}");

        string name = context.GetInput<string>();

        string name1 = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("A_ActivityA", name);
        string name2 = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("A_ActivityB", name1);

        log.LogInformation($"--------> Orchestrator ended at {T()}, isReplay={context.IsReplaying}");

        return new {
            OutputFromA = name1,
            OutputFromB = name2
        };
    }


    [FunctionName("A_ActivityA")]
    public static async Task<object> ActivityA(
        [ActivityTrigger] string input,
        ILogger log
        ) {
        log.LogInformation($"--------> Activity A started at {T()}");

        await Task.Delay(3000);
        log.LogInformation($"--------> Activity A ended at {T()}");

        return input + "-1";
    }


    [FunctionName("A_ActivityB")]
    public static async Task<object> ActivityB(
        [ActivityTrigger] string input,
        ILogger log
        ) {
        log.LogInformation($"--------> Activity B started at {T()}");

        await Task.Delay(3000);
        log.LogInformation($"--------> Activity B ended at {T()}");

        return input + "-2";
    }
```

In the console output (I've cut out everything except the output where I log time), this is what I see:

```
[1/26/2020 12:56:40 PM] ------> DurableClient Function Running at 56.40.8424.
[1/26/2020 12:56:49 PM] ------> DurableClient Function END at 56.49.5029.
[1/26/2020 12:57:03 PM] ------> Orchestrator started at 57.03.7915, isReplay=False
[1/26/2020 12:57:04 PM] ------> Activity A started at 57.04.1905
[1/26/2020 12:57:07 PM] ------> Activity A ended at 57.07.2016
[1/26/2020 12:57:24 PM] ------> Orchestrator started at 57.24.8029, isReplay=True
[1/26/2020 12:57:40 PM] ------> Activity B started at 57.40.4136
[1/26/2020 12:57:43 PM] ------> Activity B ended at 57.43.4258
[1/26/2020 12:57:53 PM] ------> Orchestrator started at 57.53.1490, isReplay=True
[1/26/2020 12:57:59 PM] ------> Orchestrator ended at 57.59.0736, isReplay=False
```

It's the 'isReplay=False' on the very last line that I can't explain.  Why is this ? Shouldn't isReplay be 'True' ?

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Durable v2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it should not be `isReplay=true` because this line is really only executed once. Whenever the Orchestrator `await` some call, it stops its own execution right there and waits for that call to finish. When it does, it runs through all the code up until its last point again - without making outbound calls again.

Since there is no further `await` behind your last logging statement, this line is only reached once.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you're right.  I had assumed that IsReplaying is set only once per invocation of the Orchestrator and never changes.  It's clear now that the value changes at different points within the Orchestrator.